Problems with integration into scientific work and the team at the beginning of a career path
In the previous series: The employer gives a job, but asks for a “plan” of work with a horizon until the end of summer
So, I was hired in the lab, part-time, remotely and with a fixed-term employment contract for 1 year. I have already received my first salary, and the second one should be coming soon.
According to the plan that I made at the request of the head of the lab, my work is microcontrollers, FPGAs, control systems + mathematical modeling. I like this complex and interesting work.
I have officially been in the organization since June 17, i.e. a little over a month. I delved a little into the lab's specialization, made several small developments in the areas from the plan during this time. They are not systematic, but rather "drafts written for myself, so that I can more or less understand the issue", although they may be useful in the future. In general, I have not yet shown myself in any way, have not received any important results.
But I still do not quite understand how I can fully integrate into their team. Recently, the head of the laboratory said that he wanted to include me in the group to work on a grant (applications are submitted in early August) and asked to send documents with watermarks to the scientific work department. And that's all. Then he told me in general terms the current task (true, after my clarifying questions). It is familiar to me and quite logical for the goal they want to achieve. Having decided that I need to somehow move and show initiative (I am used to it), I said "I will figure it out". I am worried that this was not assigned to me directly on the initiative of the head in the form of a specific task.
Is this normal, is it supposed to be like this? Even though I was officially hired, it's as if I don't exist for them and I'm left to my own devices.

You were hired into an academic lab, correct?

Also, request weekly or fortnightly meetings with your supervisor, at least for your first few months.

@Aruralreader Yes, that's correct. And I myself try to talk to him about once a week to get an idea of ​​the current tasks.

What sort of position is this?

@TerryLoring Well, it's not a postdoc. It's an engineering position. A software engineer, to be precise.

When you said "I will figure it out", what was his response? I can imagine anything from "Great! Go ahead," to "No,.I'll give you detailed instructions." Your course of action will surely depend on that response.

@AndreasBlass You'd be surprised, but that's exactly what was not answered. Then I took some generic devices and created CAD models of them to study the motion and sent him screenshots asking "which of these schemes will be used?". The answer was "we haven't dug deep yet, but we definitely need to figure out how to control these things. And always remember that all parameters must be realistic. And I think we will design these devices ourselves."

You are already having weekly meetings with him, which is good. In the meetings, tell him what you did since the last meeting, and talk about what you are going to do over the next week. I like to write down each thing I need to work on over the next week as we discuss it, then read the list back at the end. "Okay, so over the next week I'll do a and b, and then c if I have enough time." You can email a meeting summary afterwards so you both have a written record of what you agreed you would work on. This may help prompt him to suggest other things if he thinks of them.
Ask if there's a group meeting you can be included in. You can also try emailing individual members of the group to say you want to understand better how your work fits in with theirs, and ask if they have time for a 30 minute meeting to talk through what they're working on. Getting to know what other people are working on will help find opportunities to integrate better into the group.
